# Tensorflow Transformer: Hyperparameters from the base paper give gibberish results

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow2.0, machine-translation

I used the [Tensorflow 2.0 Transformer Code](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/text/transformer) and trained the model on a new data set. I used the values given in the docs for training: They had mentioned that these values are used to keep the model training faster for demo purposes.  I got decent results for 70k sentences (Span-Eng), 25 epochs.

```
num_layers = 4
d_model = 128
dff = 512
num_heads = 8

input_vocab_size = tokenizer_pt.vocab_size + 2
target_vocab_size = tokenizer_en.vocab_size + 2
dropout_rate = 0.1
```

As per the suggestion from the same docs (values from [Attention is all you need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) paper), I used the following values for 50 epochs and it gives gibberish results. Any idea what am I missing here?

```
num_layers=6, d_model = 512, dff = 2048. 

#Results
Input: Hola! cómo estás
Predicted translation: Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! 
Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model is overfitting. The model from the *Attention is all you need* paper is really huge and it is trained on approx. 4.5M sentence pairs for English-German and 36M English-French (Section 5.1 of the paper). Such a huge model can easily memorize your 70k training examples. For a model of this size, you just need much more data. You can have a look e.g., at the [ParaCrawl project](https://paracrawl.eu) if you are looking for more training data or [WMT competitions](http://www.statmt.org/wmt19).